# Eclipse - autoformatting of code

Tags: java, eclipse, format

This might be nitpicky, but I like all my code to be in the form

```
function()
{
   code
}
```

instead of

```
function() {
   code
}
```

When Eclipse autogenerates a class for me, it will use the latter format, and so I have to go through and change all of the generated methods. Is there anyway to make it so it will put it in the first format automatically? I'm using java if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click "edit" on the following panel to control the formatter:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yup.  Look in Preferences -> Java -> Cody Style -> Formatter.  you can alter a BUNCH of styles in there.

I think what you're looking for is in the Braces tab

Comment: I don't really want to downvote this question since other people seem to upvote it.  But you can easily find this information by googling 'eclipse format'.   It's not really the type of question SO should be used for.